# List of already created labels in ironpython

Tags: python, list, controls, ironpython

I have a set of labels I want to loop in a form that lists counters. Being that a long list I hope I won't have to write down every label just to edit the text.

I tried this (since ironpython uses winforms I thought it would be ok to list controls other than strings):

```
lblstat = [self.lblNWoodS, self.lblOWoodS, self.lblAWoodS, self.lblYWoodS, self.lblHWoodS,
        self.lblBWoodS, self.lblIWoodS, self.lblAResS, self.lblBResS, self.lblFResS, self.lblPResS,
        self.lblSResS]

for i in range(0, 7):
    count = somenumber
    lblstat[i].Text = count
```

And I get an error in return stating str doesn't have Text property.

I hope I explained myself. I'm sorry this question is somewhat stupid but I'm still trying to learn the ropes.

Comment: First: always show full error message. It seems you have some strings in `labelstat`, not label objects - so you can't do `"some string".Text = count`.

Comment: I don't have a normal python console, I'm using an environment that lets me do script to run in a game and I got only that string I wrote.

Comment: It is not answer but comment :)